# Tapestry - Dynamic properties for radio groups

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a loop over a radio group element. I'm trying to know which selected value each radio group has. Is there a way to dynamically generate value properties?

It works fine when it's only one radio group.

My .tml file:

```
<t:loop source="mapWaiverHeaderWithDetails.keySet()"
                    value="waiverHeader" t:id="mapWaiverHeader">            
                            <div id="waivers_${waiverHeader.code}"
                                class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div id="primary" class="panel-body editable">
                                    <t:radiogroup value="selectedWaiverDetail" encoder="waiverDetailEncoder">
                                        <ul>
                                            <t:loop source="waiverDetails" value="waiverDetail">
                                            ... 
                                            </t:loop>
                                        </ul>
                                    </t:radiogroup>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </t:loop>
```

My .java file:

```
@Property
private WaiverDetail selectedWaiverDetail;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `map:` binding prefix from tapestry-stitch (demo [here](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/mapbindingdemo))

Then you could declare:

```
@Property
private Map<String, WaiverDetail> waiverDetailMap;

void onPrepareForSubmit() {
    waiverDetailMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, WaiverDetail>();
}
```

And

```
<t:radiogroup value="map:waiverDetailMap[waiverHeader.code]" encoder="waiverDetailEncoder">
```

Comment: Thanks Lance. I'm getting a run time exception with : Exception assembling embedded component 'waiversinfo' : Could not convert 'map:waiverDetailMap[waiverHeader.code]' into a component parameter binding: Error parsing property expression 'map:waiverDetailMap[waiverHeader.code]': line 1:3 missing EOF at ':'.

Comment: You'll need to contribute the binding to the BindingSource as done [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/services/StitchModule.java#L23)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is achievable without the `map:` binding prefix with a custom getter / setter.

TML

```
<t:loop source="waiverHeaders" value="waiverHeader">            
    <t:radiogroup value="selectedWaiverDetail" encoder="waiverDetailEncoder">
```

Java

```
@Property 
private WaiverHeader waiverHeader;

@Property
private Map<String, WaiverDetail> waiverDetailMap;

@OnPrepareForRender
void onPrepareForRender() {
    waiverDetailMap = lookupMapFromDatabase();
}

@OnPrepareForSubmit
void onPrepareForSubmit() {
    waiverDetailMap = new LinkedHashMap();
}

public WaiverDetail getSelectedWaiverDetail() {
    return waiverDetailMap.get(waiverHeader.getCode());
}

public void setSelectedWaiverDetail(WaiverDetail detail) {
    waiverDetailMap.put(waiverHeader.getCode(), detail);
}
```